# Matrices and vectors of intervals

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis

I'm working on a project and think that matrices and vectors of intervals will be useful.

I'm aware about interval arithmetic, but there is little information on the internet, regarding matrices and vectors, whose elements are intervals.

Google gives https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9780898717716.ch7 and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379518304592

I'm particularly interested how the norm of such objects is defined and need more info.

So any info regarding how to handle intervals in general, and in matrices and vectors, in particular, will be useful.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The set of all intervals is not a vector space. So, a norm you desire cannot be defined. Also, it is not enough to say what would be useful. You should say what would constitute a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis , is it possible to define matrix of intervals and vectors of intervals with all operations defined for simple numbers?

Comment: Any operation you can define on intervals on the real line, you can define (entry-wise) on any arrays of such intervals.

Comment: Can i define the vector length in such way?

Comment: In what way, specifically?

Comment: Using common interval arithmetic operations: like $\sqrt{[a,b]^2+[x,d]^2}$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Any operation you can define on intervals on the real line, you can define (entry-wise) on any arrays of such intervals.

For any function $f\colon\R^n\to\R$, you can define its interval counterpart $f_{\text{intr}}$ by the formula
$$f_{\text{intr}}(I_1,\ldots,I_n):=
[i,s],$$
where $I_1,\ldots,I_n$ are intervals,
$$i:=i(I_1,\ldots,I_n):=\inf\{f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\colon x_1\in I_1,\ldots,x_n\in I_n\},$$
and
$$s:=s(I_1,\ldots,I_n):=\sup\{f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\colon x_1\in I_1,\ldots,x_n\in I_n\}.$$
E.g., if $n=2$ and $f(x_1,x_2)=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ for $(x_1,x_2)\in\R^2$, then
$$f_{\text{intr}}([-2,1],[-1,3])=\Big[\sqrt{0^2+0^2},\sqrt{(-2)^2+3^2}\,\Big]=\big[0,\sqrt{13}\big].$$

Another example: If $f(x)=x^2$ for real $x$, then the value of the corresponding interval function on the $2\times1$ interval column matrix $\begin{pmatrix}[1.1,1.2]\\ [-0.9,-0.8]\end{pmatrix}$ is $\begin{pmatrix}[1.21,1.44]\\ [0.64,0.81]\end{pmatrix}$.